# Sencha SDK Tools v3 beta Fails to Upgrade my v2.0.1 Sencha-Touch App

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've been wrestling with the new Sencha SDK Tools v3 Beta (yes, I know, beta) so that I can optimize my sencha-touch project, and it ain't going too well.

My goal is to incorporate my project optimization in our Continuous Integration build -- run the opmitimaztion code below during the build:

`sencha app build -e testing`

I've got this working on my Mac OS X machine, and am in the process of getting it to work on a Unix build server (via Jenkins).  But, because of version incompatibility between my app's version, sencha-touch v2.0.1 and Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.141, it fails.

My app is pretty small and I thought, fine, I'll upgrade my v2.0.1 app using Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.141, per their handy instructions.  According to the docs, all I need to do is this:

```
cd [my sencha-touch app dir]
sencha upgrade /path/to/the/latest/sencha-touch/sdk
```

The upgrade process *did* do something, see the output below, but my app is now broken because it can't find dependencies:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/product-selector/event/publisher/Dom.js?_dc=1348770723554 404 (Not Found) sencha-touch.js:7986
GET http://localhost:8080/product-selector/event/Dispatcher.js?_dc=1348770723544 404 (Not Found) sencha-touch.js:7986
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading './event/publisher/Dom.js', please verify that the file exists sencha-touch.js:8328
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading './event/Dispatcher.js', please verify that the file exists sencha-touch.js:8328
```

Anyone know the answer to that one?  the 404'd files, Dom.js and Dispatcher.js, are in the 'touch' directory that was created during the upgrade process.  Odd thing here is that the code is not looking in it, it's just looking at the root.  I checked the app.json file to see if there was anything that needed correcting to point it at the 'touch' dir, but didn't find anything.  Here's the output from the upgrade command:

```
~/work/product-selector/web-app (feature/upgrade ✔) ᐅ sencha app upgrade ~/frameworks/sencha/sencha-touch
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.141
[INFO ]     init-properties:
[INFO ]     init-antcontrib:
[INFO ]     init-sencha-command:
[INFO ]     init:
[INFO ]     -before-app-upgrade:
[INFO ]     app-upgrade-impl:
[INFO ]     building application
[INFO ]          [move] Moving 1342 files to /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/./.sencha_backup/2.0.1.1/sdk
[INFO ]     Renamed /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/./sdk to /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/./.sencha_backup/2.0.1.1 for backup
[INFO ]          [copy] Copying 5 files to /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/./.sencha_backup/2.0.1.1
[INFO ]     Creating new application structure
[INFO ]     init-properties:
[INFO ]     init-antcontrib:
[INFO ]     init-sencha-command:
[INFO ]     init:
[INFO ]     -before-generate-workspace:
[INFO ]     generate-workspace-impl:
[INFO ]     -before-copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INFO ]     copy-framework-to-workspace-impl:
[INFO ]          [copy] Copying 1150 files to /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/touch
[INFO ]          [copy] Copied 187 empty directories to 1 empty directory under /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/touch
[INFO ]          [copy] Copying 1 file to /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/touch
[INFO ]          [copy] Copying 1 file to /Volumes/Magnetic/Users/x/work/product-selector/web-app/touch
[INFO ]     -after-copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INFO ]     copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INFO ]     -after-generate-workspace:
[INFO ]     generate-workspace:
[INFO ]     init-properties:
[INFO ]     init-antcontrib:
[INFO ]     init-sencha-command:
[INFO ]     init:
[INFO ]     -before-generate-app:
[INFO ]     generate-app-impl:
[INFO ]     Generating new packager.json file using native packager
[INFO ]     copy-sdk:
[INFO ]     -after-generate-app:
[INFO ]     generate-app:
[INFO ]     Updating references to framework files
[INFO ]     -after-app-upgrade:
[INFO ]     app-upgrade:
```

Last note:  the upgrade process is not my main goal here, remember I only want to automate optimization of my build on my build server.  I've tried installing an older version of the SDK on my Unix build server, but it doesn't even have the same commands as the same version on my Apple laptop.  So, my second question is:

Is there anyway I can automate resource optimization in my sencha touch 2 app?  This is via jenkins, for example.

Comment: Worst case, you recreate an app and copy paste your files..

Comment: no luck, TDeBailleul.  I'm getting the same errors as above after creating a brand new project.  At least that narrows down the possible problems.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using "Sencha Cmd v3 Beta", not "Sencha SDKTools v2.0 beta 3", and yes, there's a difference.

SDK Tools: http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download/
Sencha CMD: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243153-Sencha-Cmd-V3-Beta (latest link)

The Cmd I think may not be compatible with Sencha Touch fully yet, it's more for ExtJS and Architect. Cmd I think is supposed to supersede SDKTools.... why they are both in beta at the same time, why they are named different, and why they changed the names are a huge stupid mystery to me.

When you type "sencha" in terminal you should get something like "Sencha Command v2.0.2" for v2.0 beta 3, and "Sencha Cmd v3.0" for v3.0 beta.